# Powershell equivalent of Batch command "START" to open window with Mapped Drive

Tags: powershell

This is the batch commands I use to open a window with Mapped Drive:

```
net use X: "\\SERVERNAME\FOLDER" /user:"USER" "PASSWORD"
START X:\
```

What is the Powershell version of this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both of **your commands work as-is in PowerShell**:

- **`net` refers to the `net.exe` *external program*** (a standard Windows utility), which PowerShell can equally call.

  - On Windows 8 / Windows Server 2012 or higher, you can use the [`New-SmbMapping`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/smbshare/new-smbmapping) cmdlet as an alternative to `net use`.
  - Note that while PowerShell cmdlets are *generally* more secure by not allowing passwords to be specified as *plain text* and requiring a *credential object* instead (see [`Get-Credential`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/get-credential)), this appears *not* to be the case with `New-SmbMapping`.
- While `start` is an *internal `cmd.exe` command*, **PowerShell has an *alias* named `start` for its own [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) cmdlet**; if you pass a drive specification, the two commands work the same.

  - Alternatively, you could have used the [`Invoke-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/invoke-item) cmdlet (`Invoke-Item X:\`),

    - which more narrowly supports opening only *documents and folders*, by relative or absolute paths (no `$env:PATH` search for executables is performed).
    - in the case of a drive-spec-only path such as `X:`, `Invoke-Item` opens File Explorer in *whatever directory is current* on that drive (by contrast, `Start-Process` and `cmd.exe`'s `start` open the target drive's *root* directory).

Comment: I used start and it's not working as is, it's complaining about arguments given to the process to-be-started, any hint? `START px --config=./proxy/px.ini --proxy=wwwproxy.tech.it.com:8080 --hostonly` complains with `A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument "proxy"`

Comment: @MushyPeas, use `start px '--config=./proxy/px.ini --proxy=wwwproxy.tech.it.com:8080 --hostonly'`. That is, all pass-through arguments must be specified via `Start-Process`'  `-ArgumentList` parameter, which is its 2nd positional parameter.